# Interface referencing an inner class of its implementation

Tags: java, interface

I am refactoring a piece of code and I have to made a method (lets call it `myMethod`) in one class (let's call it `TestImpl`) from `private` to `public`. Therefore, I try to add this method to its interface (`ITest`).

However, the problem is that a parameter of the method references to an inner class of `TestImpl`. i.e. something like:

```
myMethod (TestImpl.NewType var1, ...)
```

This seems a bit weird to me as the interface references to its own implementation. What is the best solution here? Or, is it really a problem?

Comment: Does `NewType` need to access private members of `TestImpl`? Will `NewType` be used only by `TestImpl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it's static class, then it shouldn't be a problem. However, I think it's better to move that `NewType` out of `TestImpl` or even create new interface to generalize this `NewType`

Answer (score 0):

It violates the DI principles, Interface should not have nay compile dependencies to its implementations. NewType should be extracted as a interface or class to outside.